# Angular: ViewChild undefined in modal/ ngTemplate

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am using the ViewChild to access a component within a modal (I used ngTemplate), but it is always set to "undefined" and therefore I cannot access its methods ...

I call the function openModal and "paginatorComponent" is undefined. I've tried also with a timeout...

```
// modal.component.ts
export class SelezionaSensoreModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('myModal') templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild(PaginatorComponent) paginatorComponent: PaginatorComponent;
  
  ngOnInit() {}

  openModal() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.templateRef, { class: 'modal-select', backdrop: 'static' });

   // Print undefined :(
   console.log(this.paginatorComponent)

  }

// modal.component.html
<ng-template #myModal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Title
        </h5>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <app-paginator (changePage)="changePage($event)"></app-paginator>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Try `@ViewChild(PaginatorComponent, { static: true }) paginatorComponent: PaginatorComponent;`

Comment: Adding `static: true` might be the solution. You can add `@ViewChild(PaginatorComponent, { static: true }) paginatorComponent: PaginatorComponent;` this means angular will create the view on `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score -1):

Try Learning about lifecycle hook, and use `ngAfterViewInit()`